# navigationBar color with alpha value

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I want to change the color of my navigation bar when I scroll up. My `scrollViewDidScroll` looks like:

```
override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let safeArea: CGFloat = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter{$0.isKeyWindow}.first?.safeAreaInsets.top ?? 0
    let alpha: CGFloat = ((scrollView.contentOffset.y + safeArea) / safeArea)
    // This label becomes visible when scrolled up
    navTitleLabel.alpha = alpha
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .yellow.withAlphaComponent(alpha)
}
```

I even tried hardcoding 0 into `.yellow.withAlphaComponent(alpha)`. But color is still visible. In case you wonder initial value (when not scrolled) of `alpha`, it is -0.9. How can I make navigation bar slowly visible as user scrolls, like `navBarLabel`.

Here is youtube link to the behaviour: https://youtu.be/75BjVK-nz4c

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by generating an image from the yellow colour you’re using. Then on scrollView didScroll just set the navigations background image to be the image you generate.

```
extension UIColor {
    func image(_ size: CGSize = CGSize(width: 1, height: 1)) -> UIImage {
        return UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: size).image { rendererContext in
            self.setFill()
            rendererContext.fill(CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size))
        }
    }
}

navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(UIColor.orange.withAlphaComponent(alpha).image(),
     for: .default)
```